# ADFS claim based authorization add generic authorization policy to allow access to all resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, adfs2.0

I'm using ADFS claim based authorization in my MVC 5 app.
My problem is i have to define all possible url into my application as policy and allow all of them by writing something like this:

```
 <claimsAuthorizationManager type="SEyc.Frameworks.Security.SEycAuthorizationManager, SEyc.Frameworks.Security">
         <policy resource="https://myip/api/planogram/post?id=1" action="GET">
        </policy>
        <policy resource="https://myip/api/planogram/GetHierarchy" action="GET">
        </policy>
        <policy resource="https://myip/api/planogram/GetHierarchy/1" action="GET">
        </policy>
      </claimsAuthorizationManager>
```

i dont want to define all these individual url because there is many uris.
Can we have something generic solution or generic policy which allow all of them

Comment: Wouldn't that be entirely up to the `SEycAuthorizationManager`?

Comment: I didn't get what you are trying to say. if possible can you please elaborate it.

Comment: As far as I know, by default the `claimsAuthorizationManager` has no functionality for reading or enforcing _any_ configuration elements. Any content (ie the policy configuration) should be parsed by the `SEycAuthorizationManager` class.